# Как отфильтровать вывод Elsaticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Структура документа (редакция)

```
{
    Id: "Идентификатор редакции",
    DocumentId: "Идентификатор документа",
    Date: "Дата создания",
    Text: ""
}
```

Как построить запрос что бы фильтровать редакции с повторяющимся DocumentId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте агрегацию.

Если вам нужно убрать все записи с дублирующимися DocumentId (только уникальные):

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "withoutDuplicate": {
            "terms": {
                "field":"DocumentId"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "withoutDuplicateDocs" {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И наоборот, если нужно показать DocumentId, которые являются не уникальными:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "duplicateCount": {
            "terms": {
                "field":"DocumentId",
                "min_doc_count": 2
            },
            "aggs": {
                "duplicateDocuments" {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "_source": "DocumentId"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Почитать подробнее можно по ссылкам:

[Terms агрегация](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

[Top hits агрегация](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)